# How to start jupyter notebook on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner for Amazon Ec2 and recently I successfully ssh to EC2 instance. yet when I tried to activate jupyter before ssh:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888
```

I get the message:

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=????????????????????
```

I copied the URL as instructed to the browser (chrome and safari), but it did not work. How could I proceed to ssh jupyter notebook? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you just didn't copied the link as it is (locahost), it is running on ec2, not on your computer. So change the server name to IP address of your EC2 instance (assuming you allowed traffic on correct ports)

There are a few guides how to access jupyter notebooks on remote servers, e. g. see
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server

If you are just playing along and don't care about security in this case, you may just update the binding IP in your *jupyter_notebook_config.py* :

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the jupyter server using the following command:-

```
jupyter notebook --ip=*
```

If you want to keep it running even after the terminal is closed then use:-

```
nohup jupyter notebook --ip=* > nohup_jupyter.out&
```

Remember to open the port 8888 in the AWS EC2 security group inbound to Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0)

Then you can access jupyter using http://:8888

Hope this helps.